# How can I allow things such as Ctrl-A and Ctrl-Backspace in a C# TextBox

Tags: c#, user-interface

I've got a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox that is multi-line but it doesn't accept commands like Control-A and Control-Backspace.

Control-A does nothing and Control-Backspace inserts a box character.

The "Shortcuts Enabled" property is set to true.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using and where it's not `accepting the command`

Comment: It's a text box, not a word processor. You get to implement that yourself. Lucky you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From MSDN on the **[ShortcutsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx)** property:

> The TextBox control does not support the CTRL+A shortcut key when the Multiline property value is true.

You'll have to implement it yourself.

Something like this should work:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            textBox1.SelectAll();
        }
        else if (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("^+{LEFT}{BACKSPACE}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, what about Control-Backspace? I use that SO MUCH and it bugs me so bad when a textbox doesn't support it.

Comment: @JDiPierro - I updated the answer to show support for Ctrl-Backspace (which is just like `Ctrl+Shift+Left_Arrow` and then `BackSpace`). This is just an example, you can google for other implementations that might better suite your needs.

Comment: Instead of textBox1.SelectAll(); use ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll(); so that the same method can be used by multiple textbox's and you can copy and paste without worrying about the textbox name.

Comment: Thanks! e.SuppressKeyPress will prevent the ding sound. You may also want to set e.Handled.

Comment: @xr280xr Thanks for the tip. Note, according to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159707(v=vs.110).aspx): "Setting SuppressKeyPress to true also sets Handled to true."

Comment: Unfortunately, the note referenced by @Blachshma is not present on all versions of that MSDN page. For example, the version for .NET 2.0 and for 4.5/4.6 don't have the note. However, it still applies.